# Memory fragmentation using std list?

Tags: c++, list, memory, std

I'm using list of lists to store points data in my appliation.

Here some examples test I made:

```
//using list of lists

list<list<Point>> ls;
for(int i=0;i<10000;++i)
{
   list<Point> lp;
   lp.resize(4);
   lp.pushback(Point(1,2));

   ls.push_back(lp);
}
```

I asume that memory used will be 
10k elements * 5 Points * Point size = 10000*5*2*4=400.000 bytes + some overhead of list container, but memory used by programm rises dramatically.

Is it due to overhead of list container or maybe because of memory fragmentation?

**EDIT:**
add some info and another example

Point is mfc [CPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/t792xy69.aspx) class or you can define your own point class with int x,y , I'm using VS2008 in debug mode, Win XP, and Window Task Manager to view memory of application
I can't use vector instead of outer list because I don't know total size N of it beforehand, so I must push_back every new entry.

here is modified example

```
int N=10000;
list<vector<CPoint>> ls;
for(int i=0;i<N;++i)
{
  vector<CPoint> vp;
  vp.resize(5);
  vp.reserve(5);
  ls.push_back(vp);
}
```

and I compare it to

```
CPoint* p= new CPoint[N*5];
```

Comment: What is the Point struct your are using?

Comment: Each node has an overhead (at least 2 pointers, prev & next). Why not use a vector of vectors instead? You also have less fragmentation with vectors since their memory is contiguous.

Comment: Define "dramatically". Each node contains two pointers to form a doubly-linked list. There's likely to be more overhead still in the heap, from allocating each one in an individual block.

Comment: 1. What operating system? 2. How are you determining the utilization? 3. What is the utilization that you see? 4. What is a `Point`? 5. Why not provide a full example that we can compile? 6. What compiler flags? 7. What compiler?

Comment: Memory fragmentation in using lists doesn't mean more memory being allocated. The problem with fragmented memory is apparent in a heavily modified list (many inserts and erases at random positions). At that point iterating over the whole list will run into a memory miss in every element (elements are not sequentially stored in memory, aka the memory is fragmented).

Comment: @BillLynch add additional info.

Answer (score 2):

It's not "+ some overhead of list container". List overhead is linear with the number of objects, not constant. There's 50,000 Points, but with each Point you also have two pointers (`std::list` is doubly-linked), and also with each element in `ls`, you have two pointers. Plus, each list is going to have a head and tail pointer.

So that's 140,002 (I think) extra pointers that your math doesn't account for. Note that this dwarfs the size of the `Point` objects themselves, since they're so small. You sure that `list` is the right container for you? `vector` has constant overhead - basically three pointer per container, which would be just 30,003 additional pointers on top of just the `Point` objects. That's a large memory savings - if that is something that matters.

[Update based on Bill Lynch's comment] `vector` could allocate more space than 5 for your points. *Worst*-case, it will allocate twice as much space as you need. But since `sizeof(Point)` == `sizeof(Point*)` for you, that's still strictly better than `list` since `list` will always use three times as much space.

Comment: Depending on how the vector is built, it could have a much larger footprint. Many vector implementations will preallocate space up to the next power of 2.